# Drupal language icon problem

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I just started a new project where I aim to provide country Icons. I use two languages in my project. My default language is English, and my problem is that in some pages it works fine, but in some other pages the English language does not work. Also I have a problem as shown below in image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGUkL.jpg]

So what am I to do and how can I remove the English cross text form here. I am new in Drupal.

Comment: The nodes where the language switcher doesn't work **do have** a translation ?

Answer (score 2):

The strikethrough effect (what you describe as 'cross text') over the language is because the specific content which you are viewing does not have content for that language in the language switch block.

The particular effect comes from the rule `.locale-untranslated` in `modules/locale/locale.css` line 2 (D7.36).

If you wish to remove it, either add content for the particular language, or add a rule as the following to your custom theme:

```
.locale-untranslated { text-decoration: none; }
```

Also for the record (I suppose you already use it) there is a module for displaying [language icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/languageicons).

Comment: thanks wtower..
for your suggestion cross text line is remove but .....how to remove english text

Comment: Do you use the module 'language icons' or how do you provide the icons?

Comment: no i am not use module 'language icons'...

Comment: i have use block ... and in block i have use language switcher

Comment: i am provide the icons

Comment: You have to be more clear and specific to get help. Do not flood with comments, edit your post to provide more details. Anyway take a look at https://drupal.org/node/1369090

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry to "spend" an answer for what should simply be a comment: I don't have reputation enough here to comment.*

For your question "how to remove English text": this is a quite dirty way, but to achieve you may simply change the previously added rule to `.locale-untranslated { display: none; }`.